# hidden photos in gallery lost/deleted/disappeared?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

So I have a problem... all my pictures in the galaxy's own 'hide photos' option have deleted. I went on holiday and took some pictures. I decided I would sort them and keep only my holiday photos in the gallery and hide the pictures of me and my friends. After a month of checking back at them couple times during the week they decided to disappear just after I had a look at them. I'm pretty sure I didn't delete them because if I did have accidently  clicked the deleted button it would take a couple of minutes for round about a 1000 pictures to delete and I did not see any box that said deleting 'whatever amount of number out of a 1000' please wait because I looked back at my phone within seconds. I've read many different forums which told me to use third party apps or going through to my files > ticking the show hidden files in the settings > clicking all files > phone/sd card storage > .hide file > island > and my pictures should have appeared..  but they did not... all I got was an empty file. I had no luck with anything so far. Please help me to retrieve these photos, they are important to me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you rooted?